# working with check boxes in kohana 2

Tags: kohana, kohana-2

I am working with check boxes in php kohana 2.
There are multiple check boxes depending on the query result and are displayed in view file.

I can check any of them and save this information in DB. I have this in my POST array that [1] is on, [3] is on but how can i check this that how many of them are checked.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ko3 default **form::checkbox** with same id's